# Using JavaScript single and double quotes for href's

Tags: javascript, escaping

I am having problem with escaping the single and double quotes inside the `href`s JavaScript function.

I have this JavaScript code inside `href`. It's like -

```
<a href = "javascript:myFunc("fileDir/fileName.doc", true)"> click this </a>
```

Now, since double quotes inside double quote is not valid, I need to escape the inner double quotes for it to be treated as part of the string - 
so, I need to do this -

```
<a href = "javascript:myFunc(\"fileDir/fileName.doc\" , true)"> click this </a>
```

The problem is, even the above code is not working. The JavaScript code is getting truncated at --  `myFunc(`

I tried with the single quote variation too - but even that doesn't seem to work (meaning that if I have a single quote inside my string literal then the code gets truncated).

This is what I did with a single quote:

```
<a href = 'javascript:myFunc("fileDir/fileName.doc" , true)'> click this </a>
```

This works, but if I have a single quote inside the string then the code gets truncated in the same way as that of double quotes one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using backslashes to escape quotes is how it works in JavaScript, but you're not actually writing JavaScript code there: you're writing HTML. You can do it by using the HTML escaping method: character entities.

```
&quot;  // "
&#39;   // '
```

For example:

```
<a href="javascript: alert('John O&#39;Brien says &quot;Hi!&quot');">...</a>
```

Comment: I think you still need to escape &#39; since once the html is parsed the value of the entity will be expanded into a ' just like the other plain single quotes inside the attribute. It should be `alert('John O\&#39;Brien says &quot;');`

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone needs to escape some thing like this:

```
<a href="www.google.com/search?q="how+to+escape+quotes+in+href""</a>
```

You can use ASCII code for double quotes `%22`:

```
<a href="www.google.com/search?q=%22how+to+escape+quotes+in+href%22"</a>
```

It is especially useful if you pass the link to JavaScript from PHP

Answer (score 1):

As a general best practice, use double-quotes in HTML and single-quotes in JavaScript. That will solve most of your problems.  If you need a single-quote in a JavaScript string, you can just escape it using \' - and you probably shouldn't be nesting literal strings any deeper than that.

As noted elsewhere, HTML entities are a possibility if the code is embedded in HTML. But you'll still have to deal with escaping quotes in strings in your JavaScript source files, so it's best to just have a consistent strategy for dealing with JavaScript.

If you are following this strategy and end up with a double-quote embedded in your JavaScript embedded in your HTML, just use the HTML entity &quot;.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, this kind of code is working without problems:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunc('...')">Click this</a>
```

With this code, do you have any problem?