# Couldn't append variable with single quote to anchor tag's title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am getting data from database that has single quotes in it.
There are no problems in getting that, I get variable with single quotes in it

ex:

```
var title="vicky's blog";
```

Now the problem is I am not able to append this variable as title for anchor tag.

I have tried using escape, unescape, replacing with regex and all that. I think i am missing out something, please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/mtXSZ/

Please refer to this jsfiddle. Inspect the anchor tag there its not having the full variable as title.

I also tried solutions provided in

[Using JavaScript single and double quotes for href's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617901/hrefs-javascript-single-and-double-quote-problem)

[jQuery single quote in JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the title value inside `""` in the html element

```
$("#testing").html('<a href="#" title="'+unescape(title)+'">hello</a>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VXhKw/)

But I would recommend

```
var title="vicky's blog's test dd \" with";

$('<a />', {
    href: '#', 
    title: title,
    html: 'test'
}).appendTo('#testing')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VXhKw/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Arun
The problem with second solution is that i have the anchor tag in the middle of variable
like that variable will be having some tr td etc before and after this anchor tag
Anyway thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Just create the anchor with jQuery and let it solve the escaping issue:

```
var $anchor = $('<a>', {
    href: '#',
    title: title,
    text: 'hello'
});
$('#testing').html($anchor);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtXSZ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put text in html you should always html encode the special characters.

## `'"<>&`

```
var title="vicky&apos;s blog";
```

Answer (score 0):

See this i think it will help you:
[image]